# How should I construct a subclass using an instance of the superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclassing, object-construction

Let's say I have the following code

```
public class SuperClass {
    protected int super_class_value;

    public SuperClass (int value) {
        this.super_class_value = value;
    }
}

public class Subclass extends SuperClass {
    protected int subclass_value;

    public SubClass(int super_class_value, int subclass_value) {
        super(super_class_value);
        this.subclass_value = subclass_value;
    }
}
```

However, now I want to be able to pass a SuperClass object into the SubClass constructor. How would I do that?

```
public SubClass(SuperClass super_class, int subclass_value) {
    //What do I do here?
    this.subclass_value = subclass_value;
}
```

Basically, I'd like to do something like this...

```
public SubClass(SuperClass super_calss, int subclass_value) {
    super(super_class.super_class_value);
    this.subclass_value = subclass_value;
}
```

But if SuperClass is more complex, I don't want to add each value to the super() call. Instead, I'd like to simply pass in an object that already exists, and use it as the super class.

I want to do this...

```
public SubClass(SuperClass super_class, int subclass_value) {
    super(super_class);
    this.subclass_value = subclass_value;
}
```

But I'm not sure if that's allowed?

---

Seems as though I can do the above, if I add a constructor to the SuperClass definition.  But what would that look like?

```
public class SuperClass {
    protected int super_class_value;

    public SuperClass (int value) {
        this.super_class_value = value;
    }

    public SuperClass (SuperClass super_class_object) {
        //What is done here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently your code looks fine... What exactly do you want to do with the `super_class` reference??

Comment: can you not pass it in subclass like you did `super(super_class_value);`?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the super class object?

Comment: Are you asking how you would pass in the `int` to the super call when you only have an instance of the `SuperClass` instead of being passed an `int` for the super class?

Comment: In reply to your current update, _I'd like to simply pass in an object that already exists, and use it as the super class._ well that is not really possible.  What you _could_ do is make a constructor in your super class that makes a copy of itself using the passed in reference.

Answer (score 3):

Don't you just want to have a [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12) for your Superclass?

```
public class SuperClass {
    protected int super_class_value;

    public SuperClass (int value) {
        this.super_class_value = value;
    }
    protected SuperClass (SuperClass super_class) {
        this.super_class_value = super_class.supper_class_value;
    }
}

public class Subclass extends SuperClass {
    protected int subclass_value;

    public SubClass(SuperClass super_class, int subclass_value) {
        super(super_class);
        this.subclass_value = subclass_value;
    }
}
```

See also a question here on SO about writing copy ctors:

[Does Java have a default copy constructor (like in C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20471989/1593077)

Comment: Yes, but super_class might be fairly complex, and I don't want to copy over every value manually.

Comment: @Tester101: Ah, but you aren't! At least, not in SubClass. SubClass just passes super_class along. As for SuperClass itself, if its construction is complicated, you might use [constructor chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171012/how-to-avoid-constructor-code-redundancy-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

> However, now I want to be able to pass a SuperClass object into the
>   SubClass constructor. How would I do that?

You are perfectly doing the same

```
public SubClass(SuperClass super_class, int subclass_value) {
    //What do I do here?
    // Do Whatever you want to do here ,
    this.subclass_value = subclas_value;
}
```

Now i think you might be thinking of how to pass Object to SuperClass from subclass then this can be done by `super keyword` in Java

- `super()` is used to invoke immediate parent class constructor.

Now for passing the Object to SuperClass , in your Subclass's constructor you very first line must be

```
super(super_class);
```

Now In your super class you must have a constructor which takes Object of itself otherwise the above line will throw compile time error

```
public SuperClass (SuperClass object) {
         // Do whatever you want to do .
          this.anyInstanceVariable=object.thatInstanceVariable;
    }
```

P.S. : I still don't understand what did you want to achieve with this , but this is the way you'll achieve it whatever you have mentioned

---

**Update**

As you said in comments you don't want to copy each single variable then you can use clone method of `Object class`

Here is an example how you will achieve it in your case

```
class SuperClass implements Cloneable{ // otherwise clone() method will throw CloneNotSupportedException

    int a;
    SuperClass obj=null; // this will point to the copy of the cloned object

    SuperClass(int a){// just to test that cloning is successfull
        this.a=a;
    }
    SuperClass(SuperClass a){
        try{
        this.obj=(SuperClass)a.clone();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        display();
    }
    public void display(){// to Verify that Cloning has been done successfully
        try{
        System.out.println("Hello from cloned Object "+obj.a);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException  { // Overridden Method
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Check out this nice Article about [Object cloning in java](http://www.javatpoint.com/object-cloning)

Comment: What would the body of the constructor in SuperClass look like?  Where "*// Do whatever you want to do .*" is, what goes there?

Comment: There you can write any valid java statement , but i think the task you want to perform there is copy constructor's work

Comment: Let's say SuperClass is more complex, and I don't want to copy over each variable. Is there a way to simply "copy" the whole object?

Comment: I think you want to create a clone of object

Comment: @Tester101 , Check out the updated part Hope it will help you and might be this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You could add getter methods inside of `SuperClass` and use them in the `SubClass` constructor.

```
public class SuperClass {
    protected int super_class_value;

    public SuperClass (int value) {
        this.super_class_value = value;
    }

    public int getSuperClassValue(){ return super_class_value;}
}

public class Subclass extends SuperClass {
    protected int subclass_value;

    public SubClass(SuperClass super_class, int subclass_value) {
        super(super_class.getSuperClassValue());
        this.subclass_value = subclass_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid this, as the super_class might be very complex

Comment: You're going to have to set the data somewhere, whether inside of SuperClass by adding an additional constructor to SuperClass or in SubClass by something similar to what I wrote here.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for a well-known example of this.  The page includes a good java example with UML diagram too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SuperClass {
    protected int super_class_value;

    public SuperClass (int value) {
        this.super_class_value = value;
    }

    Object obj = new Object();
}

public class Subclass extends SuperClass {
    protected int subclass_value;

    private SuperClass superCl = new SuperClass();

    public SubClass(int super_class_value, Object obj2 ,int subclass_value) {
        super(super_class_value);
        obj2 = superCl.obj;
        this.subclass_value = subclass_value;
    }
}
```